# Merge rows with different date values

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel

my list has about 1000 users with multiple entries with different values like row 2-10. I want to merge the values ​​for each user on a single line, like in the following example rows 13-17.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsQir.png)

**CSV:**

```
Name;Date 1;Date 2;Date 3 ;Date 4
Robin;01.02.2021;;;
Olaf;03.03.2021;;;
Olaf;;05.03.2021;;
Kim;;;;
Kim;;06.07.2020;08.08.2020;
Niko;03.04.2021;;;
Niko;;05.06.2020;;
Niko;;;08.04.2021;
Niko;;;;09.06.2021
;;;;
;;;;
Name;Date 1;Date 2;Date 3 ;Date 4
Robin;01.02.2021;;;
Olaf;03.03.2021;05.03.2021;;
Kim;;06.07.2020;08.08.2020;
Niko;03.04.2021;05.06.2020;08.04.2021;09.06.2021
```

Comment: Do you want to change the CSV source?  Or do you want to generate the results on an Excel worksheet?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can get the list of names with this formula:

```
=UNIQUE(A2:A10)
```

The formula for the dates is per-cell and assumes that each person only has one value in each of the date columns (this appears the case from your data).

```
=LET(x,B$2:B$10,IFERROR(FILTER(x,($A$2:$A$10=$G2)*(x<>"")),""))
```

This formula says "Let x be the data in column B from rows 2 to 10. Filter x for only those rows where the name in column A is the same as the name in column G on this row AND where x is not blank". The net result is you return zero (in the case of Kim for Date 1) or 1 value per name. If zero values are returned, FILTER returns an error. The IFERROR call says if there is an error, show blank. You then drag this formula down and across the four date columns in H:K.

If this formula does not work, then you might not have access to the LET function. In that case, use this:

```
=IFERROR(FILTER(B$2:B$10,($A$2:$A$10=$G2)*(B$2:B$10<>"")),"")
```